# Why is BigQuery a PAAS and Snowflake a SAAS

Tags: google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake and Big Query both are cloud data warehouse and although the architecture under the hood is little different, they solve the same purpose.

Then I cannot wrap my head around for why Snowflake is called as Saas and BigQuery is term by google as Paas.

Comment: Definitions are descriptive not prescriptive - so people decide what they mean by a term and within that definition choose what they apply that term to. So Google would define PaaS and SaaS however suits them and then say that their definition of PaaS is a better description of their product than SaaS. But ultimately it is all just marketing and of no real importance

Comment: @NickW I agree with your answer, However I am working on a deck to show case the difference between the two. And there I would have to show why they are Paas and Saas. So if I get some pointer it would help. Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the terms PaaS and SaaS - I'd just describe what the differences actually are

Comment: @danD check this url https://www.snowflake.com/trending/saas-vs-paas-vs-iaas?amp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Snowflake` was built purposely for cloud providers such as **Google Cloud Platform**, **Amazon Web Services**, and **Azure**, it requires almost no management or operational overhead same as how `SaaS` is being defined. It is a cloud data warehouse which can be hosted by the cloud platforms mentioned and passed as a distibuted software. Snowflake can also serve as PaaS, but PaaS requires more management (than SaaS) of the underlying hardware or software which Snowflake does not fall under.

`BigQuery` is categorized as `PaaS` since it is a native Google Cloud Platform data warehouse and a cloud-based platform service. It performs its function only on Google Cloud Platform and cannot run on any cloud provider, unlike Snowflake. PaaS delivers and manages all the hardware and software resources needed for application development which is being done when we are using BigQuery.

Basically, they just differ based on the scope of management and how each data warehouse is being managed. You can go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/learn/paas-vs-iaas-vs-saas) to help you better associate Snowflake as SaaS and BigQuery as PaaS.